# Sony Vegas VS After Effects for graphic / Keyframe editing

Tags: after-effects, vegas-pro, motion-graphics

I want to animate "drawings" on people's faces like " X "'s and other lines and I am aware, as far as I know, that in sony vegas that is done via individual frames.

Is there another way? Does AE do it more easily?

As a general question which software is best used for editing or should a combination of software be used e.g Sony Vegas for final cut edits and then AE for post and graphic editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Effects is definitely the right tool to use rather than Vegas for motion tracking / drawing on moving footage. [Here is a classic tutorial](https://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/demon_face_warp/) that you can watch to get a sense for how to achieve face tracking & replacement.

Vegas is much better suited for editing. After Effects can often struggle to achieve real-time playback over extended periods of time and doesn't have the tools built in the same way as a NLE like Vegas, Premiere, or Avid.